# How to trigger onClose on a multiple select box in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, events, select, jquery-mobile

how do I recognize if a user closes the box of a multiple select?

There is nothing about this in the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html).

I'm searching for something like a onClose event.

I tried already to set onBlur on the select, but didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.trigger()` custom events when any certain UX occurs:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-selectmenu-screen', 'click', function () {

    //find the select and trigger a `close` event since the overlay was clicked
    $(this).prev().find('select').trigger('close');
}).delegate('.ui-select', 'click', function () {

    //find the select and trigger an `open` event since the menu was clicked
    $(this).find('select').trigger('open');
});
```

I wasn't able to figure out exactly how to bind to the `X` (close) button for the widget but I'm sure you can to trigger a custom event.

Using the code above you can now register event handlers for the `open` and `close` events for the `select` element:

```
$(document).delegate('#select-choice-9', 'open close', function (event) {
    console.log(event.type);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AaKnG/

Comment: the console didn't log all of those events for me

Comment: @shanabus What browser are you using? I tested in: Chrome 17, Firefox 10, IE 9/8/7, Opera 11, Safari 5. You should be seeing the `open` and `close` events... Here is an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AaKnG/1/. The only difference is the notification is done through an `alert` so you can't miss it. Also, note that this only fires a `open` event when the widget is opened and a `close` event when the widget is closed by clicking outside the widget (not by clicking the `X` button).

Comment: in Chrome 18, only the `open` alert fires.

Comment: The problem with this is, that it will fire "close" on every select in the document.

Comment: Another problem: If the list is to long to open it in a listview, it will be opend in a dialog with different markup.

Comment: @Aley This answer was meant to be a starting point for you to be able to figure out your issue. There is almost certainly a better way to target the corresponding `select` elements. For instance the jQuery Mobile framework does it just fine, so maybe you can get some info out of `$.data(<select element>)`.